# Windows Workflow and compact framework

Tags: compact-framework, workflow

Can you use Windows Workflow and Compact Framework 3.5?

I've just got an evaluation version of Visual Studio 2008 and I've had a look around but can't work out quickly if there is a way of doing this.
I just don't want to waste anymore time looking around if there is no way of doing it.

Comment: Gonna take a WAG (can't find it on google) and say no.  CF barely has Linq; WF is a massive framework.  Not something you'd see on a smart device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer I've come across is a "No." at this point. I haven't been able to find anything or see anything that says otherwise as well. Looks like other folks are [asking](http://forums.microsoft.com/msdn/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=4014836&SiteID=1) as well.

Comment: Thankyou. I'm just looking into the new features of 3.5, it's a pity features such as this aren't put into the compact framework.

Comment: Though I can see why...due to the likes of space / processor constraints.

Comment: Yeah for sure. You can do so much on a mobile platform now, it'd be nice to do even more. Sometimes we get caught just expecting that we can. Oh well... I guess someone has to keep us grounded. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is 'No', although I have no definite proof. It certainly wouldn't have been in any version of compact framework earlier than 3.5. According to the release notes, it looks like compact framework 3.5 adds WCF, but no WF. Definite proof would be to try and fail and find WF dlls inside the framework itself.

This is actually in line with what I expect. WCF is obviously applicable to mobile devices, but WF less so (I would expect to see it on servers rather than clients).